# Searchbar working with Parse.com, cant get data to show

Tags: xcode5, tableview, parse-platform, searchbar

I posted a question before and know I have solved the problem with the "findObjectinbackground" issue.

Now, the data wont show in the table. I'm sure there must be something quite easy to resolve, but I just cant see it.

This is my code:

```
#import "busquedaViewController.h"

@interface busquedaViewController ()

@end

@implementation busquedaViewController

@synthesize totaldetalles;
@synthesize resultados;
@synthesize busquedaTableView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
                             // scope:(NSString*)scope
{
  // [self.resultados removeAllObjects];
    PFQuery *busqueda = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"icd_detalle"];
    [busqueda whereKey:@"DESC_ES" containsString:[searchText uppercaseString]];
    [busqueda findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:error:)];

}

 -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
    return YES;
}

- (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)results error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        [self.resultados removeAllObjects];
        [self.resultados addObjectsFromArray:results];
        NSLog(@"ACA LA DATA YA FILTRADA ...%@ ... TADA", results);
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
        return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return self.resultados.count;
   }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Identifier =@"bus1";

    busquedaCell *cell = (busquedaCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];


    if (cell == nil){
        cell= [[busquedaCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.busquedaDESC.text = @"Introdusca Busqueda";
    } else if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
     PFObject *tempDict = [self.resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.busquedaDESC.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"DESC_ES"];
   cell.busquedaCode.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"COD_4"];


    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Changed this:

```
- (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)results error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        [self.resultados removeAllObjects];
        [self.resultados addObjectsFromArray:results];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
- (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)results error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        [self.resultados removeAllObjects];
        resultados = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:results];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```